# I want to start reading more into philosophy, what should i start out with

Tags: knowledge

I have some stoic books by Epictetus and Marcus Aurelius and some Kant and the myth of Sisyphus, but I don't know where to go now.

Comment: Bertrand Russell: A History of Western Philosophy.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_History_of_Philosophy_(Copleston)

Comment: Caveat: Russell isn't exactly well known for his historical scholarship, but his book can be entertaining

Comment: I would suggest Heidegger's essay *Nietzsche's Word* in [Off the Beaten Track](https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?cm_sp=plpafe-_-all-_-soft&an=heidegger%20martin&bi=s&sortby=17&tn=beaten%20track).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend listening to Vervaeke's '[Awakening From The Meaning Crisis](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLND1JCRq8Vuh3f0P5qjrSdb5eC1ZfZwWJ)' lecture series, or the first 20 odd episodes anyway. It's a history of philosophy that focuses on understanding how to live a meaningful life, as the core job of philosophy (I give my summary of the longer history of that task here [What are some philosophical works that explore constructing meaning in life from an agnostic or atheist view?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91010/what-are-some-philosophical-works-that-explore-constructing-meaning-in-life-from/91017#91017)).

We just had a related question to yours: [learning philosophy without guidance](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/93941/learning-philosophy-without-guidance/93949#93949)

In terms of specific texts, I'd recommend '[Gödel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid](https://goodreads.com/book/show/24113.G_del_Escher_Bach)'  & Wittgenstein's '[Philosophical Investigations](https://goodreads.com/book/show/12073.Philosophical_Investigations)'  as both being readable, & provocative.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read “The Metaphysics of Being of St. Thomas Aquinas, A Historical Perspective” by Leo J. Elders S.V.D. It’s free on Internet Archive as a PDF so you can keep it. No harm in downloading it. Don’t worry if you don’t understand it, just keep plowing forward anyway.

Comment: One of the reasons I suggest this book by Elders is the all important historical perspective of the book. Another reason is that OP likes to read. He can keep this free book and reread and reread it.

Comment: I feel you haven't really made the case *why* anyone would read & reread it. If you're into Apologetics, have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Consolation_of_Philosophy ? It's an underacknowledged classic that's had a very profound impact on Christian thought & Western philosophy

Comment: @CriglCragl My interest is not in Apologetics. Elders is an excellent scholar. The book serves as sort of a backhanded treatment  of certain important philosophers from Plato to Heidegger, as well as serving as an introduction to old, complete Metaphysics.

Comment: A lot of young students today don’t understand why Hegel would go back and write an ontological Logic. Well Hegel wanted to be a full throttle philosopher a la Aquinas, Aristotle and this required a logical necessity.

Comment: @Gordon Can you add a link to the free book? I didn't find it.

Comment: @RamTobolski  try this link https://archive.org/details/leo-j-elders-the-metaphysics-of-being-of-s-thomas-aquinas-in-a-historical-perspective/mode/2up

Comment: @Gordon thanks it works

Answer (score 0):

- A very valuable anthology by the editor of the IEP , J. Fieser :

https://www.utm.edu/staff/jfieser/class/

- Kenny, New History Of Western Philosophy , that mixes the author by author approach and the branch by branch approach, offering, for each period, an overview of epstemology, metaphysics, ethics, etc.
- Lawhead, Voyage Of Discovery : A Historical Introduction To Philosophy.
- Stanford Encyclopedia Of Philosophy.
- Masterpieces Of World Philosophy In Summary Form ( both the first edition, and the second one in the 80's : https://archive.org/details/masterpiecesofwo00fran). First edition available at Archive.org : https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.128084
- Shand, Central Works In Philosophy. / Central Issues Of Philosophy
- Marc Cohen's  ( Uni Washington)  Lecture Notes on Ancient philosophy  : https://faculty.washington.edu/smcohen/320/320Lecture.html